# How to start the first Jenkins job with parameters

Tags: jenkins, cicd

When jenkins job of a newly created branch first starts, it only has "Build Now" button. Only after the first job starts, it can recognize the parameters from the Jenkinsfile and show "Build with Parameters" button.
Is there any way to config the jenkins to show "Build with Parameters" when the new branch job is created?

Comment: I turned on "Skip initial build on first branch indexing" option, so it postpones the first build until I actually click the build button. How to make the jenkins job only read the parameters but not actually run the whole pipeline?

Answer (score -1):

To start the first Jenkins job with parameters, you can follow these steps.

1. Create a new Jenkins Job:

- Go to your Jenkins instance.
- Click on "New Item" in the Jenkins dashboard.
- Enter your project name and select the appropriate project (e.g., - Freestyle project, Pipeline).
- Click "OK" to close the operation.

2. Enter the parameters:

- Scroll down to the "Build Triggers" section in your workflow.
- Check the box next to "This build is parameterized".
- Click "Add Parameter" to select the type of parameter you want (e.g., String Parameter, Boolean Parameter, Choice Parameter).
- Configure the parameter(s) according to your needs, and the name, if necessary, with a default value and description.

3. Enter the Build Steps:

- Scroll down to the "Build" section of your workflow.
- Add necessary construction steps to create desired actions.
- You can use parameters defined in your build steps. For example, if you create a String Parameter named ENVIRONMENT, you can use it as $ENVIRONMENT in your creation step.

4. Save your Business Plan:

- Click "Save" to save your project plan.

5. Run the Job with the Parameters:

- Now that your project has configuration and parameters, you can create the parameters by clicking on "Build with Parameters" from the project dashboard page.
- Enter parameter values ​​as requested.
- Click "Build" to start working on the specified parameters.

Comment: Actually my Multi-Branch Pipeline job does not have the "This build is parameterized" option. I saw the regular "Pipeline" job does have that, but I need to use Multi-Branch Pipeline job for my cicd task.